# can one get the static type of an object?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, std

I feel like this ought to be obvious, but I guess I'm being thique today.

How do I get the compiler to give me the static type of a thing?

ex:

```
auto it = m_security_look_aside.find(strPath);
if (it == m_security_look_aside.end())
    it = m_security_look_aside.insert(it, TYPE_OF(m_security_look_aside)::value_type(strPath, InternalIsLicensed(strPath)));
```

`m_security_look_aside` is a `std::unordered_map<std::string, bool>`.
`std::unordered_map<std::string, bool>` has a `value_type` typedef.

I can use `std::unordered_map<std::string, bool>::value_type(key,value)` to construct a pair that belongs in this unordered map.  But how can I go from the instance to its static type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decltype(m_security_look_aside)::value_type` - i.e. `decltype(m_security_look_aside)` can be used to denote the type of the instance variable.

But you don't really need that here. Instead you can do

```
it = m_security_look_aside.emplace_hint(it, strPath, InternalIsLicensed(strPath));
```

This "emplaces" (constructs in-place) an object of the proper `value_type` using the arguments (after the initial "hint" iterator) as constructor arguments for `value_type`.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot use a `decltype` expression directly there. You have to `typedef` `decltype(m_security_look_aside)` and then use the alias.

Comment: Why shouldn't I be able to use a *decltype-specifier* directly here? I am not aware of any such rule.

Comment: Interesting.  The emplace_hint() is great for my needs, but I was unable to get decltype(m_security_look_aside)::value_type to work.  The compiler (VS 2012 SP1) complains that ::value_type is not a member of the global namespace?!

Comment: Does it work following Gorpik's advice, i.e. `typedef decltype(m_security_look_aside) map_type; // now use map_type::value_type`? Not all compilers implement all of C++11 yet. Maybe VC++ doesn't support decltype() everywhere yet. From my reading of the standard it should work as I described and ideone online compiles it.

Comment: @JoergB I am not really sure about this. As you probably know, `decltype` can return different things depending on the usage. Reading the standard did not clarify things completely for me. Anyway, I tried using VS (same as Mordechai) and it only worked if I typedefed, hence my comment.